# How to check whether a table exists in my database

Tags: php, sql

My page

> displays "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in ....

table does not exist" I dont know where my problem is.

Here is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT * 
    FROM              
    $db_name    WHERE 
    table_name='{$_SESSION
    ["group"]}'";
    $texist=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($texist);

    if($count==1){
    echo"table exists";
    }else{
    echo "table does not exist";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE :** mysql_* deprecated in PHP.Use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL

try with

```
    if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $_SESSION["group"] . "'")) == 1)
    {
          echo "exists";
    }
    else
    {
          echo "not";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we  Select one row from table will return `false` if the table does not exist.We need to strong comparison opertator here instead of `==` you need to use `===` or `!==`

```
$result = mysql_query('select 1 from `tbl_student`');

if($result !== FALSE)
{
   echo "table is exist";
}
else
{
   echo "table isnot exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if table exists in DB or not you can use one of this two way

1.

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table_name';
```

2.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
AND table_name = 'table_name'
```

for more information see [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns false on error, instead of a resource. Check for that error before proceeding.

Example check:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: also, you're vulnerable to sql injection if you use the session value like that. Sanitize it, or preferrably use `MySQLi`